# Django: Providing Custom choices for PositiveIntegerField for inheriting classes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a class InheritAction which inherits from Action. Now what I would like to do is provide different choices for PositiveIntegerField. I know we can not override the class attributes in django. But is there a way of doing this. Thanks in advance

```
     ACTION_TYPE = (
            (1, 'Approve'),
            (2, 'Reject'),
            (3, 'More Information Required'),
            (4, 'Status Update')
            )
    class Action(models.Model):
        type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACTION_TYPE)

    INHERIT_ACTION_TYPE = (
            (1, 'Approve'),
            (2, 'Reject'),
            (3, 'More Information Required'),
            (4, 'Status Update')
            )
    class InheritAction(Action):
        pass
```

I have tried doing this...

```
InheritAction._meta.get_field('type).choices = INHERIT_ACTION_TYPE
```

But gives an error...

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override choices in the form.

```
class InheritActionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = INHERIT_ACTION_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        model = InheritAction
```

You could [use that form in the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) if you need it

As far as I know the choices option doesn't adds any constraint to database, it's just for autogenerated forms.